# Trocar texto em ícone de acordo com texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

```
<div class="modeloProduto">
<p>Massa Muscular</p>"
</div>
```

Não manjo muito de programação de site mas estou fazendo um site com o que sei, queria um script que muda o "Massa Muscular" pra um ícone

tipo assim, se estiver escrito "Massa Muscular" aparece um ícone de um braço, se estiver escrito "Emagrecer" aparece uma balança no lugar do texto

o site é esse -> https://www.standsuplementos.com/

Não tenho acesso ao HTML por isso preciso fazer tudo via script pra adicionar algo no site, agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo visto você está bem limitado então visei utilizar tudo da forma mais simples possível, vamos entender o código.

> tags : Ali vai o elemento que você quer que o código verifique
>
> searchText : Texto a ser encontrado
>
> **o for vai simplesmente varrendo todos os objetos encontrados pelo tagname e comparar seu texto, caso seja igual ele substitui o html do elemento por uma imagem, modifique conforme sua necessidade, vale lembrar que caso voce tenha em mente o lugar exato é só modificar o código para um getElementById evitando assim for!**

```js
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var searchText = "Massa Muscular";

for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  if (tags[i].textContent == searchText) {
    tags[i].innerHTML = '<img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-musclemusclemuscle-manbody-builderssix-packmuscle-boysclipartmuscle-black-and-white-1421526926358ytxdu.png" width="50px" heigh="50px">';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modeloProduto">
<p>Massa Muscular</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="modeloProduto">
<p>Teste</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="modeloProduto">
<p>Massa Muscular</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui o que queria, vou deixar a solução caso alguém queira fazer o mesmo

```js
$().ready(function () {
    $('.modeloProduto').each(function () {
        string = $(this).text('Massa Muscular');
        $(this).html('<img src="https://www.standsuplementos.com/arquivo/index/389081/icomuscle.png" alt="' + string + '" />');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modeloProduto">
<p>Massa Muscular</p>"
</div>
```

Com isso onde está escrito "Massa Muscular" aparece a imagem no lugar =D

Achei a solução aqui:
https://onelittledesigner.com/rapidweaver/rapidweaver-snippets/replacing-text-with-an-image-using-jquery/

Comment: Cuidado, você está perdendo toda a informação de .modeloProduto dessa forma, o .html altera todo o conteúdo, o correto não seria alterar apenas o texto do <p> ?

Comment: É, parece que o código que deixei não vai servir, o seu ficou do jeito que eu queria, valeu!